# Stream AVI video like Plex?

Tags: web, video, avi

I've been looking for a solution to stream .avi video files for a while now and I can't find anything.

I found the Plex tool which allows to have a web interface of the media library. And precisely Plex allows the playback of .avi video on its web interface!

I saw that it uses blob:// so it's a file that is segmented I guess?

I was wondering if you have any idea how they do this magic?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to display .avi videos in a browser, the problem is that browsers do not support .avi. So I have to transcode my videos, but this is very heavy for my server. I am looking for a solution like Plex to stream avi.

Comment: Why not convert it from avi to another format? MP4 H.264 is very widely supported